# Rspec tests fail when run in a certain order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Let's say I have two test files. File_A_spec.rb and File_B_spec.rb. When the tests in File_A run before the tests in File_B everything passes. But when tests in File_B run before File_A then tests in File_A fail.

Both files are request specs. The tests in File_A and File_B are unrelated and should have no dependencies. What could be causing this?

Comment: Please provide more information, preferably some code. Have you tried to isolate the problem?

Comment: Watch out for static variables..

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. The error the failing tests were returning was "undefined method 'locked'."

There was a scope named 'locked' in one of the models and I guess ActiveRecord did not like this. Similar to what was happening here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7421

The scope was renamed and now everything is passing.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have static variables or `before :all` clauses.

Note that `before :all` actions don't get cleaned up. You're expected to clean them up in `after :all`

Comment: I have confirmed that all static variables and the test database are being cleaned after each test. No change. The tests still fail.